# Numba - does nopython mode support list of tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, numba

I would like to clarify that this is my first experience with Numba, so I am very far from being an expert. I am trying to manually implement an easy KNN, here's the code:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def knn(training_set, test_set):
for q in range(len(test_set)):
    indexes = [-1]
    values = [np.inf]
    thres = values[-1]

    for u in range(len(training_set)):
        dist = 0
        flag = False
        dist = knn_dist(training_set[u], test_set[q], thres)
        if dist == 0:
            flag = True
        if not flag:

            '''
            Binary search to obtain the index
            '''    

            # Various code

return
```

Now, I would like to use the nopython mode of numba to optimize the code, here's part of the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in _call_incref_decref(self, builder, root_type, typ, value, funcname, getters)
    185             try:
--> 186                 meminfo = data_model.get_nrt_meminfo(builder, value)
    187             except NotImplementedError as e:

 in get_nrt_meminfo(self, builder, value)
    328                 raise NotImplementedError(
--> 329                     "unsupported nested memory-managed object")
    330         return value

NotImplementedError: unsupported nested memory-managed object
```

Both the training and the test set are lists of lists of tuples, I wonder if this data structure is supported by nopython, and if not (as it seems), which data structure could I use to make it possible? Am I forced to change numba mode?

P.s. to better clarify, an example of training/test is the following:

```
[[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 5)], [(0, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)], [(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)], [(0, 6), (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 8)], [(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does nopython mode support list of tuples?

Yes, it does. But, as your error message implies, not a *nested* list.

> Am I forced to change numba mode?

No, you are not.

---

You can trivially convert your list of tuples `L` to a regular NumPy array:

```
L_arr = np.array(L)
```

Here's a demonstration and how you can test for yourself:

```
from numba import jit

L = [[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 5)], [(0, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)],
     [(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)], [(0, 6), (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2)],
     [(0, 0), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 8)], [(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)]]

L_arr = np.array(L)

@jit(nopython=True)
def foo(x):
    return x
```

With `L` this gives an error:

```
print(foo(L))

LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
reflected list(reflected list((int64 x 2))): unsupported nested memory-managed object
```

With `L_arr`, you have a 3-dimensional NumPy array of shape `(6, 5, 2)`:

```
print(foo(L_arr))

array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [4, 5]],
        ...
       [[0, 5],
        [1, 4],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 4],
        [4, 2]]])
```

You may then wish to refactor your logic to work more efficiently with the NumPy array instead of a nested list of tuples.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much. If someone is following this thread I would like to add an information. When there is the need to iterate over a numpy array, apparently nopython of Numba works only by using the indices, (e.g. don't do "for elem in array", but "for i in range(array.shape[0])".

Comment: Just one further info, the lists should be of the same size, right? I guess numba is not able to manage different-sized lists (e.g., I would like to remove (not insert) the tuple with zero as second value).

Comment: Yep, they'll have to be the same size to for NumPy to be able to convert it into an array. NumPy / numba do not allow jagged arrays in any dimension.