# Numba with list of tuples

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I have a `list of tuples` queried from a db.

```
tuple_data = [(1.1,1,"one"),(2.1,2,"two"),(3.1,3,"three")]
```

each `tuple` will contain different data-types.

from this list i need 1st element from each tuple, so i did:

```
data = [result[0] for result in tuple_data]
```

Now i am trying to use `numba module` instead of `list comprehension`.

**So i tried below method:**

```
@numba.njit(cache = True)
def loop_faster(results):
    res = []
    for result in results:
        res.append(result[0])
```

This throws `NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning`: , i am not able to use list of tuples in iteration (as per numba docs)

So i  changed it to `numpy array` ([From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856836/numba-does-nopython-mode-support-list-of-tuples)):

```
L_arr = np.array(tuple_data)
```

now everything is fine.`loop_faster`method works.

The catch is , my original data is (float, int, str) while changing to `numpy array` its all (str,str,str) which is expected.

The problem is i want the data as `float` itself.

**So my code goes like:**

```
import numba, logging
import numpy as np

numba_logger = logging.getLogger('numba')
numba_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

@numba.njit(cache = True)
def loop_faster_1(results, n):
    res = []
    for result in results:
        res.append(result[0])
    print(res)

t1 = [(1.1,1,"one"),(2.1,2,"two"),(3.1,3,"three")]
L_arr = np.array(t1)
loop_faster_1(L_arr,0)
```

In real scenario my tuple list is huge, i convert it to `numpy array` for `numba` and again i need the data in float so i have to convert all str to float.

**Basically with numba,**

1. List of tuples
2. convert to numpy array
3. call numba method
4. convert back to float
5. use for further processing.

**but with list comprehension,**

1. List of tuples
2. List comprehension
3. use for further processing.

Is there a better way to do this using `numba`? or i just go with `list comprehension` to remove these steps while using numba.
Because with this i feel i am actually killing the very purpose of reducing time taken for loops.

Comment: `Larr[:,0]` is the first column of the array.  No need for numba.  But converting the list to array takes time.  You could get around float to string conversion by making a structured array.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `numba` to get the first column of a numpy array fast.  That's a basic indexing operation.

Your sample:

```
In [23]: tuple_data = [(1.1,1,"one"),(2.1,2,"two"),(3.1,3,"three")]
```

The obvious list comprehension:

```
In [24]: [x[0] for x in tuple_data]
Out[24]: [1.1, 2.1, 3.1]
```

The array approach:

```
In [25]: np.array(tuple_data)[:,0].astype(float)
Out[25]: array([1.1, 2.1, 3.1])
```

The list comprehension is much faster - for this small sample:

```
In [26]: timeit [x[0] for x in tuple_data]
349 ns ± 7.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [27]: timeit np.array(tuple_data)[:,0].astype(float)
15.4 µs ± 55.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The big time consumer is `np.array(...)`.  The indexing is fast.  The comprehension should scale linearly with list size.  But so does `np.array`, after all it is processing the list element by element.  There might a size where it ends up faster, but past experience suggests that's with 1000+ tuples.

An alternative is to use a compound dtype, making a structured array.  Now the floats aren't converted to strings.  But it doesn't improve timing.

```
In [28]: np.array(tuple_data, dtype='f,f,U10')
Out[28]: 
array([(1.1, 1., 'one'), (2.1, 2., 'two'), (3.1, 3., 'three')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<U10')])
In [29]: np.array(tuple_data, dtype='f,f,U10')['f0']
Out[29]: array([1.1, 2.1, 3.1], dtype=float32)
In [30]: timeit np.array(tuple_data, dtype='f,f,U10')['f0']
21.1 µs ± 1.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Here's another approach - make an object dtype array:

```
In [31]: np.array(tuple_data, dtype=object)[:,0]
Out[31]: array([1.1, 2.1, 3.1], dtype=object)
In [32]: timeit np.array(tuple_data, dtype=object)[:,0]
4.52 µs ± 9.41 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

That's better than the other arrays, those still behind the comprehension.  It makes a (3,3) array of objects, the same ones in the tuples.  It's very list-like, except it does multidimensional indexing.

The full arrays:

```
In [33]: np.array(tuple_data, dtype=object)
Out[33]: 
array([[1.1, 1, 'one'],
       [2.1, 2, 'two'],
       [3.1, 3, 'three']], dtype=object)
In [34]: np.array(tuple_data, dtype='f,f,U10')
Out[34]: 
array([(1.1, 1., 'one'), (2.1, 2., 'two'), (3.1, 3., 'three')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<U10')])
```

Comment: The reason I formed a numpy array is to use with numba method. If list comprehension is taking lesser time than all this and in my scenario I cannot use numba with list of tuples. Then I will stick to list comprehension!